# Loop update total field in procedures 

Tags: sql-server

How to loop update total field in procedures in SQL Server?

I have table 1. I want to create procedures to update total field automation.

Table1

```
Value 1  Value 2   Total

2         4
3         4
3         3
3         1
3         4
```

PROCEDURE:

```
Create PROCEDURE test1
AS

Select value1,value2,(value1*value2) as total from Table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE up_UpdateTotals
AS
BEGIN

  UPDATE Table1 SET Total = Value1 + Value2 WHERE Total IS NULL OR Total <> (Value1 + Value2)

END
```

Will update totals for where it's not set or not in sync (in case values change). Can be extended by adding parameters and such, ofcourse.

Update: Change + to * in case you need to multiply the values instead of add them together.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Total = value1*value2
```

Or you can make Total as calculated field in table1 and it will happen automatically.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s I will, but can you tell me how to find that button {} on mobile version (iPhone) ? Thanks.